# iptables utility on Android sdk emulator avd

Tags: android-emulator, iptables

I am trying to learn android os. My aim is to learn security part. I am trying to find iptables utility in file system hierarchy. Do you know where is it? Also there is no too like find or "ls -laR" or grep.
I am using android sdk and emulator avd with android os 2.2 API8

Answer (score 2):

Try to install BusyBox which contains a lot of the UN*X commands...